# How to define dependent geometries (e.g. for a male-female connector design)

Tags: modeling

Is there a way to define dependent geometries? For instance while designing a male-female components of a connector I want that if I change something in the male component - the female component will adopt itself automatically to the change (and vice versa).

Comment: you can use the slice in the bool tool , remember you should use brush for not automatically applying the modifier , should i elaborate?

Comment: Yes, please. With an example, if possible. Thank you!

Comment: wait for few minutes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plan is to use the **Bool tool** addon that is Default in blender and can be activated in Edit > Preferences > Addons ,then create a big cube
[image]

**this will act as a female port holder , where we will create our female port**

**Now you can add another small cube to be used as our male adapter**

[image]

Then select the small cube > then the big cube(please follow the order) and click  <kbd>N</kbd>
to open properties tab , go to Edit tab and expand Bool Tool to find the brushes.

[image]

now Choose the slice option .You can notice that the part of smaller cube intersecting with the mesh has sliced it to create a new block , now you can change the geometry of the original small cube to change the slicing in both big and sliced cube

[image]

This method is responsive and geometry changes in real time

for legos this can be done with a boolean brush

**Model a Lego**

[image]

**Make sure that the bottom of the lego is a little bigger and the top a little smaller** then duplicate the lego and put it a little above the first lego.
[image]
Run a boolean brush , like this (**Remember select the bottom lego first** )- [image]

Comment: Thank you! Will this work also if male/female components are parts of the same object? Like a Lego brick?

Comment: the example i have shown you easily works for usb , yess you can try this for lego also

Comment: i have edited the awnsere and added for legos also